# sql insert if other row with same attribute and date > 1 day

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert rows into a table with a date and info column. The insert should not happen if there is already a row with the same info value and a date that is >= 1 day difference to today.

assuming current date: 2017-01-03

```
id, info, date
1, a, 2017-01-01
2, b, 2017-01-02
```

new rows to insert:

```
info
c
a
b
```

expected operations:

```
c: gets inserted because no other row has the same info value
a: gets inserted because existing a has a date more than 1 day in the past
b: no insert because the time difference is not big enough
```

expected result:

```
id, info, date
1, a, 2017-01-01
2, b, 2017-01-02
3, c, 2017-03-03
4, a, 2017-03-03
```

Comment: I think you will need to create a trigger for this.

Answer (score 0):

For that constraint, you have to make a trigger to avoid the insert, this is a untested example of the trigger and you can implement whatever logic do you need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tg_triggername
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( your_logic )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( 
      -20002, 
      'can't in sert already a row with the same info value and a date that is >= 1 day difference to today' );
  END IF;
END;
```